# Stack Iterator in C++

Tags: c++, oop, iterator, stack

I want to understand what iterators are, how they are made. So int this code iterators are created for Stack.My question are

1. how we can write     Stack s2(s1), if we don't have class named Stack which has explicit constructor, insted we have StackIter class , which has explicit constructor ?
2. What does this mean:     `StackIter *Stack::createIterator()const`,we have class StackIter, then pointer on stack, I don't understand at all. Maybe when we write Stack `s2(s1)`, it comes from here ?
3. So the meaning of iterator is shown in bool operator == (`const Stack &l, const Stack &r`) ?

Thanks a lot in advance .
Any response will be appreciated

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Stack
{
    int items[10];
    int sp;
  public:
    friend class StackIter;
    Stack()
    {
        sp =  - 1;
    }
    void push(int in)
    {
        items[++sp] = in;
    }
    int pop()
    {
        return items[sp--];
    }
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return (sp ==  - 1);
    }
    StackIter *createIterator()const; // 2. Add a createIterator() member
};

class StackIter
{
    // 1. Design an "iterator" class
    const Stack *stk;
    int index;
  public:
    StackIter(const Stack *s)
    {
        stk = s;
    }
   void first()
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    void next()
    {
        index++;
    }
    bool isDone()
    {
        return index == stk->sp + 1;
    }
    int currentItem()
    {
        return stk->items[index];
    }
};

StackIter *Stack::createIterator()const
{
  return new StackIter(this);
}

bool operator == (const Stack &l, const Stack &r)
{
  // 3. Clients ask the container object to create an iterator object
  StackIter *itl = l.createIterator();
  StackIter *itr = r.createIterator();
  // 4. Clients use the first(), isDone(), next(), and currentItem() protocol
  for (itl->first(), itr->first(); !itl->isDone(); itl->next(), itr->next())
    if (itl->currentItem() != itr->currentItem())
      break;
  bool ans = itl->isDone() && itr->isDone();
  delete itl;
  delete itr;
  return ans;
}

int main()
{
  Stack s1;
  for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    s1.push(i);
  Stack s2(s1), s3(s1), s4(s1), s5(s1);
  s3.pop();
  s5.pop();
  s4.push(2);
  s5.push(9);
  cout << "1 == 2 is " << (s1 == s2) << endl;
  cout << "1 == 3 is " << (s1 == s3) << endl;
  cout << "1 == 4 is " << (s1 == s4) << endl;
  cout << "1 == 5 is " << (s1 == s5) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You seem really confused about the difference between a stack and a stack iterator.  Get those straight, and then we can answer some of these.  Or better, we probably won't have to.

Comment: Also, that's a _really_ weird iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Default copy constructor operator:**

`Stack s2(s1)`  correcsponds to the `Stack s2(const Stack& x)` copy constructor, generated by your compiler if you don't tell him to  use another one.

**2) Definition of a member function**

`StackIter *Stack::createIterator()const  { ...}` is the definition of the member function `createIterator()` that is declared in you class but was not yet defined.   Basically it returns a pointer to a StackIter.

**3) definition of an operator**

Not sure about your question.

`bool operator == (const Stack &l, const Stack &r)` defines the comparison between two stacks.  So a priori not directly related to iterators.

But indeed, this function demonstrates the use of the iterators.

*P.S:  I think you are working on an example of [this tutorial](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/iterator/cpp/1).  I'd  however warmly recommend you to read "The C++ Programming Language" or some similar books who give you full insight on working with iterator and address all the prerequisites.*

Comment: Thank you very much  for response, but we don't have Stack(const Stack *s), we have StackIter(const Stack *s), so we should write StackIter(const Stack *s), and also why is written StackIter *Stack , here insted of Stack could be any variable, lets say StackIter *s?

Comment: @Narek this isn't a mistyping, and you shouldn't change the code : the copy constructor is automatically there even if you don't have it in your source file.  Why do you want to change it ?

Comment: aaa , so if I create some class, then automatically the copy constructor is made ?

Comment: StackIter *Stack::createIterator()const
{
  return new StackIter(this);
}   why we can define createIterator() outside of StackIter,createIterator() is not friend function, friend is only class StackIter,  so as I understand it is the same if I would define this operator inside class StackIter, ??

Comment: And also can you explain please this line StackIter *Stack::createIterator()const , , why StackIter *Stack, but StackIter and also Stack are different classes .

Comment: @Narek the createIterator() is defiend in class Stack(). So it is a member function of Stack.  It's just that it returns a `StackIter*`, just as it could return an `int or a `char*``.  As you pointed out, createIterator() is not a friend of StackIter, so it can only use its public members.

Comment: I'm very sorry ,once more question , how can we use  bool operator == (const Stack &l, const Stack &r) , if in Stack class we don't have   friend bool operator == (const Stack &l, const Stack &r) ?

Comment: the operator needs to be friend only if accessing the class internals. Here it uses only public functions that are visible to any object/function outside the class

Comment: Ok , Thanks very much , I did not notice , thank you